# Subdivide a single column to multiple

Tags: sapb1

hi all
i want to know is it possible to subdivide a single column to multiple sub columns in a grid or in a matrix in **SAP B1**. 
and i am using version 8.82. i need this requirement for the display purpose.
sample format is 
month(main column)
LOP days   
 total days  Casual Leaves(sub columns)